# Subscribing to data in activated route Angular 4.4

Tags: angular

I am trying to play around router related interfaces and I found some strange behavior while checking ActivatedRoute

Scenario: I have a header which need to keep track of routes (data param exclusively) to show in header, as route change takes place in body and each route changes need to have some data associated with it.

so i am using the below code in my header component constructor

```
this.router.events
  .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
  .map((route) => {
    while (route.firstChild) {
      route = route['firstChild'];
    }
    return route;
  })
  .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
  .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
  .subscribe((event) => {
    this.routeTitle = event['title'];
  })
```

App root looks like this

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
    data: { title: 'Dashboard' }
},
{
    path: 'change-request',
    loadChildren: 'app/change-request/change-request.module#ChangeRequestModule',
    data: { title: 'Change Request' }
},
{
    path: 'change-notice',
    loadChildren: 'app/change-notice/change-
    notice.module#ChangeNoticeModule',
    data: { title: 'Change Notice' }
},
{ path: '',   redirectTo: '/dashboard',  pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/dashboard' }
];
@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
        APP_ROUTES,
        {
            enableTracing: false,
            useHash: false
        }
    )
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
],
providers: [
]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Everything works fine and i am able to show title on header but my code seems huge to get data associated with route.
so i tried

```
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data=>{console.log(data)});
```

though it is observable it is not able to trigger may be i can assume this is not event based

Goal is to find simplified version because my gut feeling says there is always a better way to do it.

Comment: What events do you expect?

Comment: I need a event to get data attached to current route without my huge code i explained above.